# Save a new record from formset instance

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I need to save a new record from the exitsing instance of inline formset. I managed to save a new instance from the parent model (`Order`), but I can't figure out how to save a new instance of a formset. The code is like this:

```
def order(request, date):
    edit = Order.objects.get(date=date, user=None)
    edit_formset = modelformset_factory(Order_items, fields='__all__', extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=edit)
        formset = edit_formset(request.POST, queryset=Order_items.objects.filter(order__date=date))
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.pk = None
            instance.user_id = request.user.id
            if formset.is_valid():
                form.save()
                formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('order')
    else:
        form = OrderForm(instance=edit)
        formset = edit_formset(queryset=Order_items.objects.filter(order__date=date))
        return render(request, 'diner/order.html', {'edit': edit, 'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "a new instance of a formset", since the point of a formset is that it contains multiple forms. But what is wrong with the code you've posed? What does it do that you are not expecting, or not do that you are expecting? What errors do you get?

Comment: I need to edit the existing record and save a new one. The problem is that the code saves a new record of the Order table, but does not create a new one in Order_items.

Comment: Presumably `formset_is_valid()` is False, but you still redirect in that case.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to correct the validity of the formset. However, the problem of saving a new record still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've come to a solution:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.cleaned_data['pk'] = None
    if formset.is_valid():
            create_order = Order.objects.create(date=form.cleaned_data['date'], user_id=request.user.id)
            new = formset.save(commit=False)
            for n in new:
                n.id = None
                n.order_id = create_order.id
                create_order.save()
                n.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=edit) 
    formset = edit_formset(request.POST) 
    If form.is_valid(): 
        instance = form.save(commit=False) 
        instance.pk = None 
        instance.user_id = request.user.id 
        form.save() 
        if formset.is_valid(): 
            add_new = formset.save(commit=False) 
            add_new.instance = instance
            add_new.save() 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('order')
```

Since while post request you are defining the instance in **formset = edit_formset(request.POST, instance=edit)** so while saving the formset it save the order_item for the old order which you name as 'edit' not fir the new one. And **add_new.instance = instance** will help to create the formset new instance.

Comment: It's not that. Formset doesn't have an 'instance' attribute, so it wont' do.